# flickr public image gallery without user login for iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, image, gallery, flickr

I want to access flickr's public image gallery for iphone application. I know that for uploading photo on flickr we must have to login. But if i want to access http://www.flickr.com/photos/********** , here "**********" is any registered Public user. I need the response in JSON format so that i can parse it and get the list of images just like we are doing RSS parsing. Please guide me how can i do it or if any sample code available than please give the link so that I can get idea how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there arethings you can certainly do using [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) without authenticating whatsoever, more specifically following methods are enough to get everything you'd need: `flickr.people.findByUsername`, `flickr.photosets.getList`, `flickr.photosets.getPhotos`, `flickr.photos.getSizes`.

Try constructing your URL similar to...

```
/*
 * Flickr service
 */
#define kFlickrAPIKey           @"<your-api-key>"
#define kFlickrAPIURL           @"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
#define kFlickrResponseFormat   @"json"
#define kFlickrNoJsonCallback   1

NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@?method=%@&api_key=%@", kFlickrAPIURL, request, kFlickrAPIKey];
for (int i = 0; i < [params count]; i+=2) {
    [urlString appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", [params objectAtIndex:i], [params objectAtIndex:i+1]];
}
[urlString appendFormat:@"&format=%@&nojsoncallback=%d", kFlickrResponseFormat, kFlickrNoJsonCallback];
```

Although you could wrap just what you need on your own, there is also a third-party library available called [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr).